# Can't access files after 18.04 re-install

Tags: filesystem

I had trouble with my laptop after updating from 16.04 to 18.04 and re-installed the OS using "something else" so that my files would be preserved. This worked and everything runs fine but I cannot access my files. A terminal window search was able to locate all my files but I seem unable to access or move them. As far as I can tell there is only one user. Any ideas?
P.S. I'm a real newbie.

Answer (score 0):

If the files were left in place while you reinstalled the operating system, it's probably just an issue of permissions, in which case you should be to fix it with a simple:

sudo chown -R username:username /home/someuser

sudo chmod -R 770 /home/someuser

Obviously replace "username" with your username and "/home/someuser" with the path to your home directory, or to the location of the files in question.

Comment: Thanks Gerowen but I can't seem to get that to work. The commands are accepted but I still don't see the files. My user name in 18.04 is my first name but before the update, it was first intitiallastname. Could you help me get that sorted out in the command line please?